# How to train image segmentation task with only one class?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, classification, image-segmentation, u-net

Is there a neural network that has architecture optimizations for segmenting only one class (object and background)? I have tried U-net but it is not providing good enough results.

I am wondering if this can be due to the fact that my dataset has different image resolutions/aspect ratios.

Comment: When you say "only one class (object and background)", in fact you are saying two classes: the object class and the background class.

Comment: To allow us help you, you should describe a few more the context: kind of images, ... . Also the expected result.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Thanks for reply. I'm trying to train a car segmentation. I have custom dataset I've collected. I expect it to have precise boundary around the car on an image.